# How to upload SignalRConnectionString stored in local.settings.json in VS to Azure functions on azure portal

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, signalr

I was able to deploy Azure Functions to run SignalR Messaging to the Azure portal, but the `local.settings.json` file which contained the `SignalRConnectionString` required to run SignalR Messaging was not uploaded. How can I add this string on the Azure portal?

Error message on Azure portal :

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService: The SignalR Service connection string must be set either via an 'AzureSignalRConnectionString' app setting, via an 'AzureSignalRConnectionString' environment variable, or directly in code via SignalROptions.ConnectionString or SignalRAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the local.settings.json file which contained the SignalRConnectionString required to run SignalR Messaging was not uploaded. How can I add this string on the Azure portal?

Please check whether you add all [Function app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#function-app-settings) that you defined in the **local.settings.json** to function app in Azure when you publish the project.

[image]

If you did not add **AzureSignalRConnectionString** for the Remote field, you can select and navigate to your function app on Azure portal, then you can update value of **AzureSignalRConnectionString** or add new application setting for your function app in **Configuration** under **Platform features** blade, like below.

[image]

Application settings

[image]

Test Result

[image]